# Dialogflow integration with Skype/teams

Tags: dialogflow-es, microsoft-teams, skype, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have integrated Dialogflow with Microsoft Teams as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/skype). It works fine. I want to add calendar [integration](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbots-dialogflow-fulfillment#5) as well. When I try to do this with separate cloud function/cloud run, it works fine in the Dialogflow console but when I test in teams, it creates a calendar event but there is no response from webhook to teams (I get the webhook response only in Dialogflow console). This is probably because the teams doesn't recognize a normal message, it has to be converted to a skype message. This is the response back from webhook:

conv.ask(`'Ok, let me see if we can fit you in.`');

How do I convert this particular message to skype message using node js?

Comment: Hi @Manasa Krishna, could you please explain more briefly for quick mitigation.

Comment: Hi @Manasa, are you still facing the issue ? could you please share more details for quick mitigation.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT 

We are trying to integrate Dialogflow chatbot with Microsoft Teams. We followed this tutorial (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/skype)
We got to a point where we’re able to send text-based basic intent mapped questions, and they’re working flawlessly.

Now, we are trying to get a response from fulfillment (instead of basic response)
We see the fulfillment responses in Dialogflow’s test console window, but we don’t see any response in the Teams window.

Comment: Not receving the response on teams window mean? Please share the repro steps?